# How to maximize the visibility of a plurilingual web site?

Tags: localization, search-engine, robots.txt

I've been told to understand how to maximize the visibility of an upcoming web application that is initially available in multiple languages, specifically French and English.

I am interested in understanding how the robots, like the google bot, scrapes a site that is available in multiple language.

I have a few questions concerning the behaviour of robots and indexing engines:

- Should a web site specify the language in the URL?
- Will a robot scrape a site in both language if the language is set through cookies (supposing a link that can change the language)?
- Should I use a distinct domain for each language?
- What meta tag could be used to help a robot in understanding the language of a web site?
- Am I missing anything that I should be aware of?

Comment: This may be better suited to serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No
3. Not necessarily, Google will infer the language. But if you use different TLD you probably get better exposure in specific countries, but you loss PageRank diluted in different domains.
4. `<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">`
5. a. You should add a link in every page, to the same page in the other languages of the 
   site.
   b. For SEO, it's better to use www.mysite.com/en/ that en.mysite.com because the PageRank is not diluted in different domains.

Answer (score 0):

> Should a web site specify the language in the URL?

No, not necessarily.

> Will a robot scrape a site in both language if the language is set through cookies (supposing a link that can change the language)?

No. You should use a `content-language` attribute as suggested by Eduardo. Alternatively, `<html lang='en'>` will do the same job AFAIK.

> What meta tag could be used to help a robot in understanding the language of a web site?

See above

> Should I use a distinct domain for each language?

The Stack Overflow consensus (I'm sorry, I can't find for the life of me find the relevant questions! We had huge discussions on this, maybe they were closed as not programming related), is: Yes, have a different domain for each country if you want to maximize search engine visibility for that country.